# Why and how do I fix a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 error?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, error-handling, program-entry-point

I'm trying to get this library book sorting program to work. If anyone can look over the code and explain to me why this is messing up, I would really appreciate it. I had this code working a few months ago but upon revisiting it, this error has appeared.

Comment: You didn't post any code. Make sure to post it here as text. Also, have you looked up that error? It's quite common.

Comment: Check the length of the Array first.

Answer (score 0):

Since Index `0` is out of bounds, your array seems to be empty (`length = 0`). Thus accessing any element (even at position 0) is invalid.

If this error occurs while you try to fill the array, please note, that arrays have fixed length in java.